# Unable to pass a subclass instance as argument instead of superclass

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, polymorphism

In my code I have class `McdGraphicsScene` that inherits from `QGraphicsScene`, but when I try to pass a pointer to an instance of `McdGraphicsScene` to `QGraphicsView::setScene(QGraphicsScene* scene);` I get the following error:

```
../MeriseModeler/merisemodeler/mcdui.cpp: In member function 'void McdUi::setModel(McdModel*)':
../MeriseModeler/merisemodeler/mcdui.cpp:34:42: error: no matching function for call to 'QGraphicsView::setScene(McdGraphicsScene*)'
../MeriseModeler/merisemodeler/mcdui.cpp:34:42: note: candidate is:
In file included from ../../.qt5/5.0.0/gcc/include/QtWidgets/QGraphicsView:1:0,
                 from ../MeriseModeler/merisemodeler/mcdui.cpp:10:
../../.qt5/5.0.0/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsview.h:161:10: note: void QGraphicsView::setScene(QGraphicsScene*)
../../.qt5/5.0.0/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsview.h:161:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'McdGraphicsScene*' to 'QGraphicsScene*'
```

here is the code of the class

```
class McdGraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT

    // Methods and attributs
};
```

Comment: Did you implement all virtual methods properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using any [forward declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) of `McdGraphicsScene`?

Make sure that the actual class definition is visible at the call site. If there is only forward declaration available, the calling code cannot deduce that `McdGraphicsScene` inherits from `QGraphicsScene`.